# Getting error: The smart card requires drivers that are not present on this system

Tags: windows-8.1, smartcard, hyper-v

All,
I am getting an error when trying to login with my smart card to a hyper-v guest:
"The smart card requires drivers that are not present on this system."

Any Ideas?

I am trying to use my smart card on a Hyper-V guest
-Running Windows 8.1
-Microsoft image
-Joined to the domain
-I don't see a smart card reader in device manager, but not sure if I should in Hyper-V Guest

With a host
-Running 8.1
-Not joined to the domain
-With integrated card reader
-With TPM enabled
-The smart card reader appears in device manager and has the latest driver
-The smart card appears in device manager when it is plugged in
-Connected with wired LAN

With a connection (rdp)
-That has smart cards option enabled (checked)

I have tried an external USB card reader and get the same result.
My card works on other machines that are not Hyper-V guests.
I have tried installing the smart card drivers from Lenovo on the guest which does not help.
I have searched ITWEB and binged for a solution but can't find one.

Anyone have any ideas of what I can do to get this to work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have got this to work now. Apparently you need a driver for the smart card itself as well and the reader. Installing this driver on my VM Guest Fixed the issue.

**What I did:**

Go to:
http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=ge…

**And get:**

=Gemalto - Other hardware, Smart Cards - Gemalto IDPrime MD Smart Card

=Windows 7,Windows 8,Windows 8.1 Drivers,Windows Server 2008 R2,Windows Server 2012,Windows Server 2012 R2 Drivers

=Get latest version (8.4.3.0 in my case)

**Then**

Download the driver from your cart to a directory

Unzip it

Right click on the .inf and click install

Try your card (no reboot necessary for me)

Comment: Thanks for reporting back this issue! Without any programming specific details, this question is off topic though.

Comment: Any suggestions on where I should have posted it?  It is related to setting up a development environment for doing programming.

Comment: See above: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User." – Flexo". I can see how you require it for development (and I had a similar requirement some time ago). But I also have requirements for setting up a printer - not directly a programming related Q/A either.

Comment: I noticed you can also find smart card drivers directly on the reader manufacturer's support website, e.g. http://support.gemalto.com/index.php?id=pc_usb_tr_and_pc_twin#.Ws5Hw0xFzvU Neither this nor windows update did help for my instance of the same issue, however.